# Hey,how i can get in to the first element of the folder?

Tags: java

private void parsexmlfile() {
        Properties property = new Properties();

```
    try {
        InputStream stream = new FileInputStream("abc.properties");
        property.load(stream);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    try {
        // final File folder = new File("/home/you/Desktop");
        final File file = new File(property.getProperty("db.filenew"));
        File files[] = file.listFiles();


        for (File fileone : files) {

            if (fileone.isFile()
                    && fileone.getAbsolutePath().endsWith(".xml"))
                ;
            System.out.println(fileone.getCanonicalPath());
            DocumentBuilderFactory builderFactory = DocumentBuilderFactory
                    .newInstance();
            DocumentBuilder db = builderFactory.newDocumentBuilder();
            dom = db.parse(file);
            parsedocument();
            if (file.renameTo(new File(property.getProperty("db.fileold")
                    + file.getName()))) {
                System.out.println("moving  done...");
            } else
                System.out.println("not moving...");

        }
```

but i am getting the exception like

```
oracle.xml.parser.v2.XMLParseException; systemId: file:/D:/Accessing/sync/Stores/; lineNumber: 1; columnNumber: 1; Start of root element expected.
    at oracle.xml.parser.v2.XMLError.flushErrors1(XMLError.java:320)
    at oracle.xml.parser.v2.NonValidatingParser.parseRootElement(NonValidatingParser.java:329)
    at oracle.xml.parser.v2.NonValidatingParser.parseDocument(NonValidatingParser.java:291)
    at oracle.xml.parser.v2.XMLParser.parse(XMLParser.java:207)
    at oracle.xml.jaxp.JXDocumentBuilder.parse(JXDocumentBuilder.java:155)
    at javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilder.parse(Unknown Source)
    at com.ssg.read.ReadXmlFile.parsexmlfile(ReadXmlFile.java:101)
    at com.ssg.read.ReadXmlFile.run_Store(ReadXmlFile.java:71)
    at com.ssg.read.ReadXmlFile.main(ReadXmlFile.java:440)
```

how i can solve this problem?please help me...

Comment: I suspect you meant `db.parse(file)` to be `db.parse(fileone)`. (It's not at all clear why you have an empty `if` statement, by the way - what's that meant to achieve?)

Comment: And what happened, exactly? What was the content of the file that it was trying to parse? (You're currently trying to parse *all* files in that directory, not just XML...)

Comment: actually there are many sub folders inside stores ...but its not getting the path of first folder...so showing like  "Start of root element expected".so i hope prob with that

Comment: That didn't answer either of the questions I asked. Print out the name of the file that you try to parse just before you parse it - then when you look at the output, ask yourself whether you'd *expect* that to parse as a valid XML file...

Comment: sry for that.answer for your first question is that if statment is  using to get all .xml file and for 2nd:it was trying to parse .xml file along with its attributes.

Comment: Your current `if` statement does *nothing* - it checks to see if it's an XML file or not, but then doesn't really use the result of the check. And you still haven't said what happened when you used `fileone`, or which file it was trying to parse. You need to put a *lot* more effort into this question in order to make it answerable - please read http://tinyurl.com/stack-hints

Comment: am sry abt that... since i m new here..am not able to figure out exactly.in brief.. "i need to store all the attributes in x no of xml files from x no of folders ."

Comment: Well that's still a very unclear description, and it's not clear how it relates to your code, or why you've got an empty `if` statement. Read the page I linked to, and edit your question.

Answer (score 1):

You have an empty (null) if condition.

```
if (fileone.isFile()
                && fileone.getAbsolutePath().endsWith(".xml"))
            ;
```

This means, you will just evaluate every file and/or directories within the folder that's pointed by property `db.filenew`. So you may need a brace and remove semicolon from the end.

```
if (fileone.isFile()
    && fileone.getAbsolutePath().endsWith(".xml")) {
    //then parse the xml file
}
```

Comment: @uneducated_Brilliant: Then maybe you don't have any `.xml` files in that directory?

Comment: i have .xml in multiple folders.i need to access those folders accordingly.and need to parse each and every xml file.

Comment: @uneducated_Brilliant: It sounds like you need to recurse down subdirectories then. Your current code doesn't do that.